# How to comapct/minfy JavaScript like this file

Tags: javascript

How can I get a Javascript file to minity like this?

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){e=function(c){return(c<a?'':e(parseInt(c/a)))+((c=c%a)>35?String.fromCharCode(c+29):c.toString(36))};if(!''.replace(/^/,String)){while(c--){d[e(c)]=k[c]||e(c)}k=[function(e){return d[e]}];e=function(){return'\\w+'};c=1};while(c--){if(k[c]){p=p.replace(new RegExp('\\b'+e(c)+'\\b','g'),k[c])}}return p}('K M;I(M)1S 2U("2a\'t 4k M 4K 2g 3l 4G 4H");(6(){6 r(f,e){I(!M.1R(f))1S 3m("3s 15 4R");K a=f.1w;f=M(f.1m,t(f)+(e||""));I(a)f.1w={1m:a.1m,19:a.19?a.19.1a(0):N};H f}6 t(f){H(f.1J?"g":"")+(f.4s?"i":"")+(f.4p?"m":"")+(f.4v?"x":"")+(f.3n?"y":"")}6 B(f,e,a,b){K c=u.L,d,h,g;v=R;5K{O(;c--;){g=u[c];I(a&g.3r&&(!g.2p||g.2p.W(b))){g.2q.12=e;I((h=g.2q.X(f))&&h.P===e){d={3k:g.2b.W(b,h,a),1C:h};1N}}}}5v(i){1S i}5q{v=11}H d}6 p(f,e,a){I(3b.Z.1i)H f.1i(e,a);O(a=a||0;a<f.L;a++)I(f[a]===e)H a;H-1}M=6(f,e){K a=[],b=M.1B,c=0,d,h;I(M.1R(f)){I(e!==1d)1S 3m("2a\'t 5r 5I 5F 5B 5C 15 5E 5p");H r(f)}I(v)1S 2U("2a\'t W 3l M 59 5m 5g 5x 5i");e=e||"";O(d={2N:11,19:[],2K:6(g){H e.1i(g)>-1},3d:6(g){e+=g}};c<f.L;)I(h=B(f,c,b,d)){a.U(h.3k);c+=h.1C[0].L||1}Y I(h=n.X.W(z[b],f.1a(c))){a.U(h[0]);c+=h[0].L}Y{h=f.3a(c);I(h==="[")b=M.2I;Y I(h==="]")b=M.1B;a.U(h);c++}a=15(a.1K(""),n.Q.W(e,w,""));a.1w={1m:f,19:d.2N?d.19:N};H a};M.3v="1.5.0";M.2I=1;M.1B=2;K C=/\\$(?:(\\d\\d?|[$&`\'])|{([$\\w]+)})/g,w=/[^5h]+|([\\s\\S])(?=[\\s\\S]*\\1)/g,A=/^(?:[?*+]|{\\d+(?:,\\d*)?})\\??/,v=11,u=[],n={X:15.Z.X,1A:15.Z.1A,1C:1r.Z.1C,Q:1r.Z.Q,1e:1r.Z.1e},x=n.X.W(/()??/,"")[1]===1d,D=6(){K f=/^/g;n.1A.W(f,"");H!f.12}(),y=6(){K f=/x/g;n.Q.W("x",f,"");H!f.12}(),E=15.Z.3n!==1d,z={};z[M.2I]=/^(?:\\\
```

I have a script that will only work when it is like that, If I view the source in my browser though I am able to view it as regular code and make edits to it, but unless it is in that form, it gives me errors.

I just need to know how to pack it like that, I have tried the minification tools online and even the JS UglifyJS but they do it like this instead...

```
if(typeof SyntaxHighlighter=="undefined")var SyntaxHighlighter=function(){function b(a,b){return a.className.indexOf(b)!=-1}function c(a,c){b(a,c)||(a.className+=" "+c)}function d(a,b){a.className=a.className.replace(b,"")}function e(a){var b=[];for(var c=0;c<a.length;c++)b.push(a[c]);return b}function f(a){return a.split(/\r?\n/)}function g(a){var b="highlighter_";return a.indexOf(b)==0?a:b+a}function h(b){return a.vars.highlighters[g(b)]}function i(a){return document.getElementById(g(a))}function j(b){a.vars.highlighters[g(b.id)]=b}function k(a,b,c){if(a==null)return null;var d=c!=1?a.childNodes:[a.parentNode],e=
```

Comment: how can a script work only when it's packed? can you provide a demo with js packed and unpacked?

Comment: @Fabrizio Calderan I have the packed script working, I take the unpacked script and I get errors, I use the packed script and I get no errors and everything works, the script in question are the javascript syntax script by Alex Gorbatchev. I don't know if that is the core problem but it will be the start in my debugging by being able to pack my own version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
eval(function(p,a,c,k,e,d){…
```

This is the trademark sign of the [packer by Dean Edwards](http://dean.edwards.name/packer/). Encode as Base62 en use shrink variables.

Comment: Worth pointing out that you'll suffer a slight performance hit using this method because the browser has to do more work to interpret your code. Depending on the complexity of your app it may or may not be noticeable.

Answer (score 1):

use this http://javascriptcompressor.com/

and enable base62 encode to pack your code

Comment: That would be **base62**. Original script is by Dean Edwards.